# Load Jsp page from Another Jsp page inside IFrame

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, servlets

I am trying to load a JSP page in IFrame under webapp/WEB-INF/jsps like following:-

```
<iframe id="frame1" frameborder="1" src="framebody.jsp" width="100%" height="350px">
```

Note:- Both  the pages are in same directory webapp/WEB-INF/jsps.

Getting Exception on browser console : -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 .
```

Comment: check your application console logs.

Comment: `src="framebody.jsp"` will be in html on client side and it will make another request to your server. So you need to pass url in src attribute: `src='iframe_body_url'` and make a handler on server that will return framebody.jsp as a result of iframe_body_url

Answer (score 0):

Files located within `WEB-INF` folder can not be accessed directly.
You need to make the src to a servlet request,and make the response of the request to the jsp file.

```
<iframe id="frame1" frameborder="1" src="queryBody" width="100%" height="350px">


@RequestMapping("queryBody")
   public String queryBody(){
     return "framebody.jsp";//make sure you have set the prefix to /WEB-INF/jsps
}
```

Comment: Can I put my jsp at any public place so that iframe can access it.

Comment: @PankajKanti you can put it outside `WEB-INF`,but if you access jsp directly,it might not convert to html automatically